# How to control Webpage dialog with python

Tags: python, dialog, html

When I try to automatically download a file from some webpage using Python, 
I get Webpage Dialog window (I use IE). The window has two buttons, such as 'Continue' and 'Cancel'. I cannot figure out how to click on the Continue Button. The problem is 
that I don't know how to control Webpage Dialog with Python. I tried to use 
winGuiAuto to find the controls of the window, but it fails to recognize any Button type 
controls... An ideas?

Sasha

A clarification of my question:

My purpose is to download stock data from a certain web site. I need to perform it for many stocks so I need python to do it for me in a repetitive way. This specific site exports the data by letting me download it in Excel file by clicking a link. However after clicking the link I get a Web Page dialog box asking me if I am sure that I want to download this file. This Web page dialog is my problem - it is not an html page and it is not a regular windows dialog box. It is something else and I cannot configure how to control it with python. It has two buttons and I need to click on one of them (i.e. Continue). It seems like it is a special kind of window implemented in IE. It is distinguished by its title which looks like this: Webpage Dialog -- Download blalblabla. If I click Continue mannually it opens a regular windows dialog box (open,save,cancel) which i know how to handle with winGuiAuto library. Tried to use this library for the Webpage Dialog window with no luck. Tried to recognize the buttons with Autoit Info tool -no luck either. In fact, maybe these are not buttons, but actually links, however I cannot see the links and there is no source code visible... What I need is  someone to tell me what this Web page Dialog box is and how to control it with Python. That was my question.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking... can you please clarify exactly what you're trying to do, with a code sample?

Comment: You mention python, so are you using some code? can you post that?

Comment: Are you trying to download a file with a python script? If so, open the page with your browser, click the 'Continue' button and see what happens. Are you getting the file then? Maybe you should try other approach and just let Python do the download job while you figure out the final URL for it yourself?

Comment: It sounds like a Javascript window. What happens if you turn off Javascript in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and you don't want to. When you ask a question, try explaining what you are trying to achieve, and not just the task immediately before you. You are likely barking down the wrong path. There is some other way of doing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The title 'Webpage Dialog' suggests that is a Javascript-generated input box, hence why you can't access it via winGuiAuto. What you're asking directly is unlikely to be possible.

However, making the assumption that what you want to do is just download this data from the site, why are you using the GUI at all? Python provides everything you need to download files from the internet without controlling IE. The process you will want to follow is:

1. Download the host page
2. Find the url for your download in the page (if it changes)
3. Download the file from that url to a local file

In Python this would look something like this:

```
import urllib,re

f = urllib.urlopen('http://yoursitehere') # Original page where the download button is
html = f.read()
f.close()

m = re.search('/[\'"](.*\.xls)["\']/', html, re.S) # Find file ending .xls in page
if m:
    urllib.urlretrieve(m.group(1), 'local_filename.xls') # Retrieve the Excel file
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use selenium Python bindings:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import alert
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
class AlertsManager:
    def alertsManager(self,url):
        self.url_to_visit=url
        self.driver=webdriver.Ie()
        self.driver.get(self.url_to_visit)
        try:
            while WebDriverWait(self.driver,1).until(EC.alert_is_present()):
                self.alert=self.driver.switch_to_alert()
                self.driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
        except TimeoutException:
            pass


if __name__=='__main__':
    AM=AlertsManager()
    url="http://htmlite.com/JS006.php" # This website has 2 popups
    AM.alertsManager(url)
```